# How can axioms be independent if one of the cases of $A{\implies}B$ is that they are simply both true?

Tags: logic

An axiom $P$ is independent if there are no axioms $Q$ such that $Q{\implies}P$, which can be written, by the standard definition used in first-order logic, as ${\lnot}(Q{\land}{\lnot}P)$.

We obviously know that there are theories with two or more independent axioms. Two such axioms are alwats true in such a theory. In this theory, where $A,B
$ are these axioms, it's therefore true that ${\lnot}(A{\land}{\lnot}B)$. How does this comply with "it's not true that there exists $A$ such that $A{\implies}B$"?

Comment: If $T$ is a theory with axioms $P,Q,\cdots$, you need to consider the theory $T'$ that is the theory $T$ minus the axiom $P$

Comment: In your definition (that is not very well formulated but that's not too important), you should stress that $Q\implies P$ should be proved *without using $P$*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of **independence** is wrong, not to say your claim about two independent axioms (sentences?) being always true. What kind of source did you get your claims from?

> Given a first-order theory $T$, a sentence $φ$ over $T$ is **independent** over $T$ if and only if $T \nvdash φ$ and $T \nvdash \neg φ$.

Equivalently:

> Given a first-order theory $T$, a sentence $φ$ over $T$ is **independent** over $T$ if and only if $(T + φ)$ and $(T + \neg φ)$ are both consistent.

It is also possible that any proof of a sentence over $T$ requires the use of more than one axiom of $T$, which invalidates your definition of independence.

Furthermore, independent sentences have no truth value apart from a model. By definition of independence, any independent sentence over $T$ is true in some model of $T$ and false in some (other) model of $T$. So it is totally meaningless to talk about the truth value of an independent sentence without specifying the model. Also, given two distinct independent sentences $φ,ψ$ over $T$, there is no systematic way to tell whether they are compatible or not over $T$, meaning that it could be that $T \vdash φ \lor ψ$, or that $T \vdash \neg ( φ \land ψ )$. It could also be neither.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we only say that $B$ is independent of a theory (with axiom $A$) if in particular $B$ is not itself an axiom of this theory.
In the theory that has only $A$ as axiom, yuo cannot prove $B$, hence you cannot prove $A\to B$.

Answer (score 0):

For instance: "The Axiom of Choice is independent of ZF." Note that the axioms of ZF (Zermelo-Fraenkel without Choice) don't contain the Axiom of Choice. As you point out, it would make no sense to say that the Axiom of Choice is independent of ZCF (Zermelo-Fraenkel without Choice).